# how do I code SUM() into my own custom function in MySQL? (Error Code: 1415)

Tags: mysql

I need to make a custom function to give the sum of "credits" in a given "track", I've figured out the entire syntax and I've solved everything... but I can't use a function like SUM() inside my function, there for, I will need to program my own function to do what SUM() does.

I've tried searching everywhere on google to try and see how the SUM() function itself works, so I can try to emulate it inside my function without calling the SUM() function. help with this would be appreciated.

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists TotalTrackCredits $$   

create function TotalTrackCredits(varTrackID int(10))
returns int
begin

    select sum(courses.courseCredits) from courses
    join trackcourses join tracks
    where courses.courseNumber = trackcourses.courseNumber
    and trackcourses.trackID = tracks.trackID
    and tracks.trackID = varTrackID;

end $$

delimiter ;
```

I expect it to return a number of credits based on which trackID is selected, but instead it gave me the "Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a function".

Comment: Why can't you can use `Sum()` inside your function?

Comment: @JNevill As I stated in my question, it returns an error code. 1415 to be specific. however, the question has been answered already by Reymond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SQL into?

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists TotalTrackCredits $$   

create function TotalTrackCredits(varTrackID int(10))
returns int
begin

    return ( 
       select sum(courses.courseCredits) from courses
       join trackcourses join tracks
       where courses.courseNumber = trackcourses.courseNumber
       and trackcourses.trackID = tracks.trackID
       and tracks.trackID = varTrackID
    ); 

end $$

delimiter ;
```

As a test case below works as we don't have user case with table structures and or data.

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists TotalTrackCredits $$   

create function TotalTrackCredits(varTrackID int(10))
returns int
begin

    return ( 
       select sum(varTrackID) from dual
    ); 

end $$

delimiter ;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jqGffJKYWvWsDbofy4XiEe/1)

> **Comment of sindripal** 
>   okay, this worked, I only needed to do "SET GLOBAL
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;" then it worked, thanks man

The testing ground (db-fiddle) has that setting aswell i assume as the error didn't happen there.

> By default, for a CREATE FUNCTION statement to be accepted, at least
>   one of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA must be specified
>   explicitly. Otherwise an error occurs:
>
> ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
>   or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
>   (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
>   variable)

Quote from [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html)

> **comment part of sindripal** 
>   if I should learn a different way to enable creating the function, how would 
>   you go about it?

So the SQL code should be

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists TotalTrackCredits $$   

create function TotalTrackCredits(varTrackID int(10))
returns int reads sql data
begin

    return ( 
       select sum(courses.courseCredits) from courses
       join trackcourses join tracks
       where courses.courseNumber = trackcourses.courseNumber
       and trackcourses.trackID = tracks.trackID
       and tracks.trackID = varTrackID
    ); 

end $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: okay, this worked, I only needed to do "SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;" then it worked, thanks man. I appreciate it.

Comment: @sindripal  `create function TotalTrackCredits(varTrackID int(10))
returns int reads sql data`  ...   don't alter log_bin_trust_function_creators  as makes [Stored Program Binary Logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html) unsafe

Comment: @[Raymond Nijland] Is it okay to modify the log_bin_trust_function_creators if it's a server located on the developer computer that has no data of any value that I am using for school/homework? or should I learn a different way to do this without risking security? if I should learn a different way to enable creating the function, how would you go about it?

Comment: *"if I should learn a different way to enable creating the function, how would you go about it?"* see mine first comment @sindripal like the manual saids *"By default, for a CREATE FUNCTION statement to be accepted, at least one of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA must be specified explicitly. Otherwise an error occurs: "* i also updated the question..

Comment: @[Raymond Nijland] Thank you man, works great, I also reset the log_bin_trust_function_creators back to 0. Thanks for helping me learn and keeping my future databases more secure.